# Is it possible to create an API that can CREATE, DOWNLOAD and CALL data from a Swrve (CRM) to Power Bi

Tags: api, powerbi, crm

I have my data in a CRM called Swrve. I would like to create an API that can CREATE, DOWNLOAD, and CALL a report from that database, to Power Bi.
Once a report is created, you are given a report code that you can then used to download the report  and then call that report.
Is it possible to write an API that can do this? Or possibly two?

I've googled this in length as well as talking to various people, but with no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I would like to do this with some other CRMs too.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Do you want to download data from your CRM into Power BI, with a report you design in Power BI, or do you want to create a report (i.e. a thing with controls and visuals) in your CRM and make it available in PBI as-is somehow? The former is certainly possible, using either one of the many connectors already available in PBI or by (for example) writing your own HTTP API and then using `Web.Contents` to access it. You would first need to figure out how your CRM stores its data, and how you can retrieve it, then make this available to Power BI.

Comment: I would be the former, I want to download the data from my CRM into Power BI. The problem is I can't figure out how to automate the download weekly. It seems each time I want the report, I would need to download the data to create a 'report code' which I would then use to download the data form the database. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: In Power BI, you'd create a dataset that loads the required data upon which reports can be built. Datasets can be automatically refreshed on a schedule, with a maximum of 8 times per day (for your use case even once per day would suffice). I don't know how your CRM works; if you need it to generate a code that you then exchange for actual data it just means more work is needed in a custom connector/API to take care of that on behalf of Power BI (which of course doesn't know about the specifics of accessing your system). There is no one-size-fits-all approach here, it depends on your CRM.